# integral of square of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-integrals

What is expectation of 
$$\int_0^t B(s)^2ds$$
where $B(s) is standard Brownian motion. Is the integral a well known random variable?

Answer (score 5):

The expectations is easy to calculate, using Fubini's theorem, which applies since the integrand is positive:
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\int_0^t B(s)^2 ds\right] = \int_0^tE[B(s)^2]ds = \int_0^ts\,ds = \frac{t^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$